# UIScrollview + AutoLayout + Scroll with Drag Effect

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a scroll view with (for example) 3 subviews. They are aligned one above another, with constraints keeping them 16 points apart.

When I scroll up and down the scroll view, I want there to be some lag between the views, almost like a spring animation. Imagine pulling a spring up: the top ones move fast, while the lower ones take a bit longer to come up and bounce around before settling.

I tried animating a change in the constant values for the constraints, but this does not give the effect I am going for.

Is this effect possible, and how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with UIKit Dynamics, introduced with iOS 7. Check out the [2013 WWDC Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/) 217 "Exploring Scroll Views", second topic.

Comment: In the video, they use a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout. Do you know if this method also works for UIViews connected by auto layout constraints?

Comment: It certainly won't work in the same way, but perhaps refactoring as UICollectionView is feasible.

Comment: UICollectionView is using UIScrollView not visa versa so you will probably need to work with UICollectionView items + springy or create your own calculating system for subviews. Anyway you will need UIKit Dynamics